# Wordpress Admin Form to select file from media

Tags: wordpress, plugins

How to create a form field that will allow me to select a file from the media such as linking to a PDF file (or DOCX, XLSX, etc.) that has already been uploaded to the Media library within WordPress.

Scenario:
I've already added the document, abc.pdf, to my media library. Now I need to provide a link to that document. I have a custom form (not made from a plugin) and need to provide "supporting documentation".

I've googled the topic but all that I'm finding are plugins and that is not what I am after.

Can someone point me in the right direction? The search terms I'm using are not yielding any results that are helping me (e.g. the results I'm finding are how to upload a file and approaches the topic as a user; I need to know how to do this as a developer). I hope that makes sense.

UPDATED
Just for clarity, the form is accessible by admin so I put "admin" in the title of my SO Question. For what I'm trying to accomplish with this question, I would not expect "Admin" to have any bearing on the solution.

Comment: cant you get all media and filter this? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11662/get-all-images-in-media-gallery?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-the-wordpress-media-uploader--cms-22011

Comment: @Tobias - I haven't tried it yet but that link looks very promising, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This SO answer does exactly what I need:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29066/how-to-add-wysiwyg-editor-tinymce-to-plugin-options-page-compatible-with-wordp

And the Wordpress maze of codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor